# Array of object arrays bound to d3 selection not updating

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here is my [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/luyititoyifa/1/) demonstrating my issue with selections and binding data.

As you can see from the visualization and the console output, the data bound to the links does not update, though the data bound to the nodes does. The node data is an array of objects and the link data is an array of object arrays at each step. There is something wrong with the way I'm updating my link data because the data gets "stuck" on the data that it was initialized with. I assume that this has to do with updating `curStep` and then calling `.data(traces[curStep])`

Any insight would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I have a long-winded version of this question as well, but I plan to delete it soon

Comment: Don't use `links.selectAll("path")`, use `gBlocks.selectAll("path")`.

Comment: Thanks, that was half my problem. My other half was having to update all of the trace attributes after every step. Somehow, this wasn't a problem in my first implementation, so I'm a little puzzled.